# Facebook send request link doesn't work when clicked on in the Android notifications menu

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-requests

I've added in the Send Requests Facebook functionality into my app by following this tutorial on the Facebook developer site:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests

It works absolutely fine when the user opens the Facebook for Android app and clicks on the notification from there: the user will be redirected to the app, or if they don't have it, they will be redirected to the page on the Play Store.

However, when the user clicks on the notification from the Android pull-down menu, it redirects the user to the Facebook app where it displays the left side of a page that says "The link you fo" (the rest is cut off).

I can't tell if it's a problem in the app or in Android's settings on my phone.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know GameRequests, which were previously Requests now work only with apps that are defined as games in the consule.